# android | BLE write value to characteristic

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've got problem with writing value to BLE characteristic. I send correctly array of bytes , however the major is not being changed. I've got few characteristics and there's no problem to read them. However there's a problem with writing to every of them new value. This is my "reading" part :

```
  @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();
                for (BluetoothGattService service : services) {
                    registerService(service);
                    characteristics = new ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>();
                    characteristics.add(services.get(4).getCharacteristics().get(0));
                    characteristics.add(services.get(4).getCharacteristics().get(1));
                    characteristics.add(services.get(4).getCharacteristics().get(2));
                    characteristics.add(services.get(4).getCharacteristics().get(3));
                    characteristics.add(services.get(4).getCharacteristics().get(4));
                    characteristics.add(services.get(4).getCharacteristics().get(5));
                    characteristics.add(services.get(4).getCharacteristics().get(6));
                    characteristics.add(services.get(4).getCharacteristics().get(7));
                    characteristics.add(services.get(4).getCharacteristics().get(8));
                    characteristics.add(services.get(4).getCharacteristics().get(9));
                    characteristics.add(services.get(4).getCharacteristics().get(10));
                    characteristics.add(services.get(4).getCharacteristics().get(11));
                    characteristics.add(services.get(5).getCharacteristics().get(0));
                    characteristics.add(services.get(6).getCharacteristics().get(0));
                    if (Characteristics.PARAMETERS_SERVICE_UUID.equals(service.getUuid()))
                        registerParametersCharacteristics(characteristics);
                    Log.e(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered: " + service.getUuid() );
                    requesReadCharacteristics(gatt);
                }
                callback.connectedStateChanged(true);
            } else
                disconnect();

    }

    public void requesReadCharacteristics(BluetoothGatt gatt) {
        if (characteristics.get(characteristics.size() - 1).getUuid().equals(Characteristics.TEMPERATURE_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "requesReadCharacteristics: TRUE");
        }
        if (characteristics.get(characteristics.size() - 1).getUuid().equals(Characteristics.ACCELEROMETER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "requesReadCharacteristics: TRUE");
        }
        gatt.readCharacteristic(characteristics.get(characteristics.size() - 1));
    }
```

To write new value to characteristic I've got method :

```
public void setMajor(int major) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[]{(byte) (major & 0xFF), (byte) ((major >> 8) & 0xFF)};
        if (majorCharacteristic != null) {
            BluetoothCommunicationManager.getInstance().add(new WriteCharacteristicCommand(majorCharacteristic, bluetoothGatt, bytes));
            Log.e(TAG, "setMajor:" + Arrays.toString(bytes));
        }
        else
            Log.e(TAG, "setMajor: NU" + Arrays.toString(bytes));
    }
```

and a class to handle it :

```
public class WriteCharacteristicCommand implements BTLECommand {
    private final BluetoothGatt gatt;
    private final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic;
    private final byte[] value;

    public WriteCharacteristicCommand(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, BluetoothGatt gatt, byte[] value) {
        this.gatt = gatt;
        this.characteristic = characteristic;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public void process() {
        characteristic.setValue(value);
        gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
    }
}
```

I found on logs, that when I set new value every characteristics are reading again ... twice, and than again fo the third time , and that's when old value is being set up again. Strange but that what's happen'. Any idea what I'm doing wrong ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can only have one outstanding GATT operation at a time (read / write a descriptor / characteristic). You need to wait for the corresponding completion callback (onCharacteristicRead etc) until you can send the next request.